# How to get static (non-template) content using Velocity API?

Tags: java, velocity

The Velocity API provides a way to get templates by name (which is then loaded using Velocity's resource manager). Is there a similar way to get static content?

Given a VelocityEngine, you can get a template like so:

```
Template template = velocityEngine.getTemplate("/path/to/resource.vm");
```

but there is no such thing as:

```
ContentResource content = velocityEngine.getContent("/path/to/resource.png");
```

The latter method is provided by the underlying VelocityInstance, but VelocityEngine does not expose it. Is there an alternative way to get to static content?

Comment: Check if there is misunderstanding: What u want is the static content of the vm template file, even if it contains the VTL script? If it is, why not use java resource api to fetch it? Or just treats it as a text file and access it by io api?

Comment: Indeed, the static content may or may not be a VLT script. To avoid duplication I would like to use the same resource manager/loader for loading templates as for loading other resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own resource loader and use it to load regular resources and also templates for velocity.

First you should create a class which extends org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ResourceLoader
(for example "**com.mycomp.MyLoader**")

Second, you should configure your velocity engine to use the new resource loader:

```
VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
ve.setProperty("MyLoader.resource.loader.class","com.mycomp.MyLoader");
ve.setProperty("resource.loader","MyLoader,file");
```

The property resource.loader tells Velocity the available loaders names. the "file"
is the default loader. 
when ve.getTemplate will be called, Velocity will iterate over the loaders list. first it will call your custom loader (MyLoader). if the resource won't be found, it will look for it using the default file loader.

Third,
You can use MyLoader to just load any file you want. (not only velocity template)
you can do it using:

```
MyLoader loader = new MyLoader();
loader.getResourceStream("/path/to/resource.png")
```

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. The ResourceLoader does exactly what it should do. The problem is that I cannot get the ResourceLoader to do it because I cannot access the ResourceLoader object directly, and the VelocityEngine does not expose the getContent() method of ResourceLoader like it does the getTemplate() method.